# properly accessing an instance out of scope and templating for mutiple instances

Tags: javascript, scope, templating

I've made some notes on my jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cjros/2xuxb2kp/) and as you can see so far, I have a Timer model with a a couple of methods.

```
var TimerModel = function (timerName, startTimerLimit) {

this._init = function () {
    this.setTimerName(timerName);
    this.startTimerLimit = startTimerLimit * 1000; // in milliseconds
    this.setInitialTimerDisplay(startTimerLimit);
    this.isTimerActive = false;
};

this.setTimerName = function (timerName) {
    $('#display-timer-name').html(timerName);
};

this.setInitialTimerDisplay = function (timerLimit) {
    $('#display-timer-limit').html(timerLimit);
};

this.startTimer = function () {
    this.isTimerActive = true;
    var startingCountdown = setInterval(function () {
        if (this.startTimerLimit === 0 && this.isTimerActive) {
            clearInterval(startingCountdown);
            this.isTimerActive = false;
            alert('Time is up!');
        } else {
         this.startTimerLimit -= 1000;
         $('#display-timer-limit').html(this.startTimerLimit / 1000);
        }
    }.bind(this), 1000);
};

this.pauseTimer = function () {
    if (this.isTimeActive) { 
        clearInterval(/* how would i access this.startTimer()'s setInterval? */) 
    };
};

this._init();
```

}

```
$('#start-timer').click(function () {
    var timerName = $('#set-timer-name').val();
    var initTime = parseInt($('#set-timer-limit').val());
    var timer = new TimerModel(timerName, initTime);
    timer.startTimer();
});

$('#pause-timer').click(function() {
    // how would I properly access my 'timer' instance that I created in the '#start-timer' action event?
});
```

- I was wondering how to access the instance I created in my start button click event (line 48). If you look a little lower on my pause button click event, I'm trying to figure out how to access that same instance but do not necessarily know how to do that.
- Another question I have is about trying to access or "communicate" with another method within the Timer model. As you see on line 39, I'm trying to clearInterval from the this.startTimer method but do not really know how to access that function/variable.
- On a broader note for knowledge on javascript, would this format of my code be a proper way of creating a model (class)? Does anyone have any other recommendations I should read about or take a look into formatting my code to make it easier and avoid some of the problems I've had above?

  - Another important question that I would like to know is this: what if I wanted to create more than one instance of this timer model so that I can start/stop/pause each one individually? How should I be thinking about formatting this code now? Do I need a superclass or something to monitor all these instances? Is this where templating comes in (definitely can't have more than one same DOM element id)? I know how to do this with knockout by creating viewModels and templating them out; I just wanted to better understand how to do this natively (jQuery being used as an exception).

Really appreciate the help in advance. So much to learn!

Comment: You should really bring you JSFiddle code into the question. Links can be broken, and since you're referencing the code from your question, it needs to be available here.

Comment: @jwatts1980 thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to do some digging into JavaScript scoping. Objects/variables created within the scope of access of a function will remain in scope as long as the function exists. For example, if you create the interval variable in the main body of the `TimerModel`, you can use throughout the functions.

```
var TimerModel = function (timerName, startTimerLimit) {
    var startingCountdown = null;

    this.startTimer = function () {
        this.isTimerActive = true;
        startingCountdown = setInterval(
        //......
    };

    //And it can be easily cancelled later
    this.cancelTimer = function() {
        clearInterval(startingCountdown);
    };
};
```

So you create a variable `var tm = new TimerModel("test", 20);`.
As long as the variable `tm` exists, functions/methods withins the object instance will be able to access `startingCountdown`.

As to storing objects, one little jQuery trick I would mention is the `$.data()` function. `$.data()` is a way to store arbitrary data into an element in the DOM. Example usage would be:

```
var el = $("someSelector");
var tval = parseInt(el.val());
var tm = new TimerModel("test", tval);
el.data("timer", tm);
```

Now the object `tm` is stored in the DOM. To retrieve it later:

```
var tm = $("someSelector").data("timer");
```

Or you can do something like store the name of the timer:

```
el.data("timerName", "testTimer");
var timerName = el.data("timerName");
```

The scoping stuff I mentioned above also works in jQuery. So in the ready script any variable that you create can be used through the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Create a variable to hold the timer
    var timer = null;

    $('#start-timer').click(function () {
        var timerName = $('#set-timer-name').val();
        var initTime = parseInt($('#set-timer-limit').val());

        //Create the timer on the variable, or maybe see if the user wants
        // to cancel the timer if it already exists.
        if (timer) {
            if (confirm("Cancel the current timer?")) {
                timer.destroy(); //<==assumes this method is created.
                timer = null;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }

        timer = new TimerModel(timerName, initTime);
        timer.startTimer();
    });

    $('#pause-timer').click(function() {
        if (timer) timer.pause();
    });
});
```

If you want to take this idea up a notch, and want to be able to create any number of timers, then you it would be good to create an object to handle the timers. You have some timer names already in use. You could add a name property to your existing `TimerModel`.

```
var TimerModel = function (timerName, startTimerLimit) {
    this.name = timerName;
};
```

So you can access the timers later by name.

```
var TimerModelCollection = function() {
    var timers = [];

    this.addTimer = function(name, time) {
        var tm = new TimerModel(name, time);
        timers.push(tm);
        return tm;
    };

    //Other methods to remove timers, and such, as well as a way to access
    // them by name would be needed too.
    this.getByName = function(name) {
        for(var i in timers)
            if (timers[i].name == name) 
                return timers[i];
        return null;
    };

    //etc, etc...
};
```

Using some of the other methods mentioned above, you may be able to figure out how to create timers, save them or their names for retrieval later.

Hope this helps!